# Careers: "Prevent this experience from appearing in header" checkbox does nothing

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs

I have a few projects in my Experience section marked as "Current", but I only want one of them to show up at the top of my CV/profile. I see the "Prevent this experience from appearing in header" checkbox on each item, but choosing it doesn't change what appears in the header, and it doesn't persist when I refresh the page. (Yes, I did click "save"!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re right, it wasn’t persisting. Thanks for the heads-up, it should work correctly now.

Comment: Thanks, Matt, it works now! But it would be nice if the header would update immediately so I could see what the result looked like, instead of having to refresh first.

Comment: Yup, that’s in the works…